# Why won't git let me fetch from two remotes?

Tags: git, github

> I followed [these instruction](http://synacy.com/technology/synacy-wordpress-project) to set up two git remotes.

When I `git remote -v` this is what I get (except with my own repo names)

```
all git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git (push)
all git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git (fetch)
all https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
github  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
github  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
staging git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git (fetch)
staging git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git (push)
```

After reviewing my config it looks a little different the the one in the example:

**My git config**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "staging"]
    url = git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
[remote "all"]
    url = git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git
    url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = all
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

**Git config in the example**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/(remote name)/*
[remote "staging"]
    url = git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/(remote name)/*
[remote "all"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
    url = git@git.wpengine.com:staging/example.git
```

### How can I get `all https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)` to show up when I `git remote -v`?

**

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not readily see "what is the problem?" Perhaps you should *edit* your question to show us what you *expected* to see, e.g. from the example? You show us the difference in the configuration *(which, superficially, does not seem to be significantly different with regard to the remotes),* but you don't show us the  `git remote -v` output *(that you presumably expected to see ...)* from the example. Kindly make your question, *here,* as complete as you can.

Comment: Also, the *title* of your question seems to me to be quite-unrelated to its body. In the *title,* you ask "why git won't let me fetch from two remotes?" (And yet, you really don't explain, yet, just what you *mean ...)* So, when you edit your question, would you please start by clearly explaining that? (Let the body of your question clearly and immediately link-back to the title.) Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're trying to have one remote (e.g. "all") that fetches from two URLs, I don't think that's possible - how would it reconcile the two if they differ? You can *push* to multiple URLs in one remote because there is no chance of a conflict between the two (just the chance of your changes conflicting with those on the remotes, but that does not change whether you have one or multiple URLs.)

Comment: Hey Mike I made my question bold (maybe it was hard to see since it was at the end of the question).

Comment: Could you try to explain why you want to have **one remote** with **two fetch** urls?